Accuracy of MRO ephemeris
I am trying to understand if I pick a point on the Martian surface, say the Airy-0 Crater, with what accuracy can I predict the earth time the MRO will pass directly overhead?
It's my understanding that the ephemeris of the MRO is calculated twice weekly using radio astronomy to within an error of a few meters.
I also that the ephemeris of Mars can be measured via VLBI, short term 90 to 150 days, to an error of approximately 50m.
It seems to me that the Ephemerides is now precise enough that the time the MRO passes overhead of a certain point can be predicted with a small amount of error.

Why don't you add a link to the ephemeris you are talking about - and while you are at it, double check to see if the information is not already there? And of course, the concept of "directly overhead" is probably not useful, just focus on the accuracy of the ephemeris itself.

The ephemeris of Mars tells you about its orbit around the Sun, which you don't need for this. What you do need is its rotation vector, to learn how your chosen point on the Martian surface moves with respect to the satellite's orbital plane. You have an estimate of the orbit uncertainty, and are asking for a time uncertainty, but you also need an angle uncertainty, to put a number on how close to "directly" overhead it gets. If you make the tolerance too tight, the satellite might not enter that field of view for centuries, so it's better to ask how well elevation angle can be measured.

@RyanC Thanks for your comments, How would I calculate the rotational vector between the MRO and Airy-0 Crater? I want to make a Predictive model, that if the MRO was to image the Airy-0 what would be the uncertainty in the prediction? The MRO has as I understand it, excellent instruments to measure Elevation angles and altitude.  Any suggestions on where to start calculating such a model?
